# How can I see the code that HotSpot generates after optimizing?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm-hotspot

I'd like to have a better understanding of what optimizations HotSpot might generate for my Java code at run time.

Is there a way to see the optimized code that HotSpot is using after it's been running for a while?

Answer (score 10):

You will need to start the JVM with the options `-XX:+PrintAssembly` and `-XX:UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`, but PrintAssembly requires the JVM to have the hsdis binary (HotSpot disassembler). The hsdis binary is not distributed with the JVM due to license incompatibility, so you will need to [compile hsdis yourself](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/wiki/Building-hsdis) or find a [prebuilt hsdis binary from an unofficial web site](http://fcml-lib.com/download.html).

To make sense of the output, a tool like [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) is useful. Follow [its instructions](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/wiki/Instructions) to write the debug information to a log file which can be analyzed in JITWatch.

Comment: Yep, -XX:+PrintOptoAssembly is the key.

Comment: Note: `PrintAssembly` is the new flag. `PrintOptoAssembly` is the old flag, which I believe requires a debug build of the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2009-February/001255.html