# How does Java handle division by zero?

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

Does it simply check if divisor is different from zero every time there is division done (even in JIT-ed code)?

I mean how VM manages to throw an exception without being previously killed by the OS?

Comment: What do you mean by "previously killed"?

Comment: It doesn't. You have to handle it yourself in a `catch` block at some point, or else the user gets an Excetion in his face, which is not nice.

Comment: The OS won't kill the VM for a divide-by-zero. The VM will terminate if such an exception is not catched.

Comment: Division by zero is caught at hardware level and results in interrupt being called with usually leads OS to stopping the process (I'm asking how it is caught internally in VM implementation not language itself)...

Comment: My understanding is that division by zero results in the hardware marking a special bit to indicate what happened.  Java presumably just checks that bit to see whether or not it needs to throw an exception.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo yeah the OS doesn't kill anything but the VM commits suicide ;-)

Comment: @mrpyo you missunderstood the JVM. Bytecode which is something like Assembler code runs on a Virtual machine. Not on the "real hardware" per se

Comment: @ITroubs when JITed, it does

Comment: @Andreas thanks. something new I learned...

Comment: @ITroubs I was about to put it in those terms, but then I stepped back for something more politically correct :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208546/in-java-5-0-statement-doesnt-fire-sigfpe-signal-on-my-linux-machine-why

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In an Unix environment, in which division-by-zero is `signal`led via `SIGFPE`, the JVM will have installed a signal handler which traps the `SIGFPE` and in turn `throw`s an `ArithmeticException`. If you're interested in the internals, see e.g. `man signal`

What I believe the OP is asking is based on the fact that, until/unless a `SIGFPE` handler is in place, most processes will take the default action on receiving this signal, which is to terminate. Thus, e.g. a C program

```
 int main (int argc, char** argv) { int n = 5 / 0; }
```

… if it even compiles, will be killed by the default `SIGFPE` → `SIG_DFL` action. The JVM's handler instead issues the (`catch`able) `RuntimeException` so that these exceptions can be handled in a native-seeming way.

As several others pointed out, and just for completeness, in point of fact the `SIGFPE` generated from the kernel is generally mapped from a special interrupt from the processor itself; thus, the “pipeline” is something like

- CPU error trap interrupt → kernel interrupt handler → `SIGFPE` `SIG_DFL` → process death

or

- CPU error trap interrupt → kernel interrupt handler → `SIGFPE` handler in JVM → `RuntimeException` `ArithmeticException` in user code

On non-Unix platforms the handling is analogous.

Answer (score 8):

Java handles the situation like any other language. A divide by zero error generates a processor exception which triggers an interrupt. The interrupt is "read" by the operating system and forwarded to the program if a handler is registered. Since Java registers a handler, it receives the error and then translates it into an `ArithmeticException` that travels up the stack.

Answer (score 6):

The JVM catches the Division by Zero like this with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fpe_handler(int signum) {
      printf("signal is %d", signum);
      printf("JVM throws an ArithmeticException here...\n");
      exit (1);
}

int main() {
      int a = 5;
      int b = 0;
      signal(SIGFPE, fpe_handler);   
      printf("%d\n", a / b); 
      return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it prints this:

```
el@apollo:~$ gcc -o catch_sigfpe myc.c

el@apollo:~$ ./catch_sigfpe
signal is 8
JVM throws an ArithmeticException here...

el@apollo:~$
```

The operating system synchronously raises a SIGFPE exception, the C program catches it, and then the java constructs and feeds you the ArithmeticException and cleans up after itself to stop the Java program.

See more about the signal returned here:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.user.aix64.60%2Fuser%2Fsighand.html

Answer (score 2):

OS sends signal to the process. Default handler would stop the process, but you can define own handler for it. I bet java VM does.