# Why is branch prediction faster than no branch at all?

Tags: java, performance

Inspired by this question:
[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

I wrote my own branch prediction experiment:

```
public class BranchPrediction {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        long start;
        long sum = 0;

        /* No branch */
        start = System.nanoTime();
        sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; ++i)
            sum += i;
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
        System.out.println(sum);

        /* With branch */
        start = System.nanoTime();
        sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; ++i)
            if (i >= 0)
                sum += i;
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
        System.out.println(sum);

        /* No branch (again) */
        start = System.nanoTime();
        sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; ++i)
            sum += i;
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
        System.out.println(sum);

        /* With branch (again) */
        start = System.nanoTime();
        sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; ++i)
            if (i >= 0)
                sum += i;
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

The result confuses me: according to program output, the loop with a branch is reliably faster than no branch loops.

Example output:

```
7949691477
-5340232226128654848
6947699555
-5340232226128654848
7920972795
-5340232226128654848
7055459799
-5340232226128654848
```

Why is it so?

Edit:

- Disassembled class shows Java compiler did not optimize (miss) anything (https://gist.github.com/HouzuoGuo/5692424)
- The Java benchmark technique used by author of [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) is the same as mine.
- The machine is an Intel core i7, running Linux 3.2 64-bit and Oracle JVM 1.7 64-bit
- When I supersize the number of loop iterations, with-branch loop runs multi-SECONDS faster than non-branch loop.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing the effects of compiler/JIT optimizations?

Comment: I get very different numbers:
897432717
1236491513
884481456
3572587417

Comment: Java 1.7.0_21 64-bit hotspot VM on Linux 3.2 64-bit Intel core i7

Comment: Obligatory: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Java 1.7.0_11 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: These results are incorrect, in mine it runs as expected

Comment: So is there a problem in the Java code? Original author of "Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?" used the same approach to benchmark his/her program.

Comment: You must understand that Java doesn't work like C++ to begin with. Start reading the link posted by @MarkPeters and then redo your benchmark.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion Luiggi, however the author of "Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?" wrote the experiment in both C++ and Java. If you see an obvious error in my benchmarking technique, please suggest.

Comment: I supersize the experiment and the result reliably shows the for loop with a branch is multiseconds faster than the loop without branch.

Comment: If you read the answer from your posted link, the author says it has done the benchmark with C++ and Java, but **never says how was done**.

Comment: Try printing out the `sum` variable between each test. As it is right now, the JIT could legally optimize everything out.

Comment: Thanks Mystical. I have modified the program to reset `sum` before each loop and print out the result.

Comment: Perhaps [HotSpot's generated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551781/how-can-i-see-the-code-that-hotspot-generates-after-optimizing) will yield some insight.

Comment: I think at this point, you'll need to do an assembly dump. Since AFAICT, you're doing the benchmark correctly.

Comment: Thank you Luiggi and Mark. However, I don't think JVM is so unpredictable, if multi secconds difference is not enough to prove that one loop is faster than the another, what can?

Comment: disassembled class file is attached.

Comment: You are very likely seeing hotspot's influence on your values. Consider the fact that each iteration of your 'loops' is being completed in under a nanosecond, it's pretty obvious you are seeing the jvm optimize your loops. For example, it would be very trivial for the If statement to be removed since it could easily tell that 'i' will always be greater than or equal to 0. Another optimization, would be to instead of incrementally add each value per loop it might do multiple additions and skip a few iterations as you aren't forcing anything to be done with the intermittent values.

Comment: I'd suggest writing these tests into something like JUnit, where your test is not so much effected by `compiler/JIT optimizations` (for better accuracy).

Comment: Your benchmark methodology is somewhat questionable: Diagnostic output of the HotSpot JIT compiler reveals the method recompiled several times during the timing phase (this is called [deoptimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optimization#Deoptimization)). You should not be taking a new code path during measurement, as this will cause you to measure a mixture of unoptimized code, optimization, and optimized code. While this is unlikely to account for a difference of a full second for such simple code, you might keep than in mind for the next benchmark (or use a tested library).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running the same experiment on my other machines (Intel servers and workstations), I may conclude that the phenomenon I experienced is specific to this laptop CPU (Intel i7 Q740M).

==== 6 months later edit ====

Check this out: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/03/intel-i7-loop-performance-anomaly/

Comment: What did you achieve on other machines?

Comment: My other machines run Intel Xeon and Intel Core 2, both running Linux 64-bit and Oracle JVM. The Xeon CPU shows no real difference between the loops and the Core 2 CPU shows that branched loop runs noticeably slower than no-branch loop.

Comment: This i7 CPU must be particularly good at adding a positive number into a negative number.

Comment: Idk i have Intel i3, I made programs such as yours up there I didn't achieve much with optimizing with if statements and exclusions.

Answer (score 2):

Have in mind that JVM is optimizing execution internally, and there are caches inside your PC that make computing faster. Since you have so powerful processor (many independant cores) it is not strange. Also note that there is code that runs under the Java code which maps to machine code of your PC. Just type code as optimized as you can, let JVM worry about it.

EDIT: Machines and hardware like big load, they operate with more efficiency then. Especially caches.